# Unable to publish the azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-deployment

We have a **Azure Function** which is built in **.Net Framework 4.6** and recently we have updated the **Azure Functions** with **.Net Framework 4.8** which works good in locally. So we tried to publish this to Live by going to select the existing Azure Function as below image.

[image]

But we are unable to publish due to below error (**Publish has encountered an error**).

[image]

Can you please suggest me If I missed any settings/configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, azure function v1 support dotnet framework4.7 as the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#languages) shows:
[image]

I test it in my side with dotnet framework 4.8 and show the same error message as you, so i think you'd better change the dotnet framework from 4.8 to 4.7.

Comment: We have recently received the email From Microsoft to upgrade .Net Framework 4.8. So need to upgrade the Azure Functions. Email is **Action recommended: Test your apps using .NET Framework 4.8 by July 14, 2020**

Comment: @Bojjaiah. Based on the statement released on the [Azure App Service blog](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/06/09/NET-Framework-4.8-is-coming-to-App-Service.html), it is only the test period of `.net framework 4.8`, you can only test your Azure Function locally in advance, if you want to publish your Azure Function to Azure, please wait for the official notice.